# Query Param value is not updated in angularjs router?

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router, angular-ui-router-extras

I have defined my state with one constant param(page), one dynamic param(id), one query param(date) like this.

```
   $stateProvider.state('test', {
   url: '/page/:id?date',
   controller: 'MyCtrl'       
 });
```

I am calling this state from my controller with passing query param like this

```
$state.go("test", {id: '5',date:'06/09/2016'});
```

After called this state I am getting params,

```
console.log($stateParams.id) -> '5';
console.log($stateParams.date) -> '06/09/2016'(as expected results)
```

Again I am calling the same state from my controller without passing query param like this.

```
$state.go("test", {id: '7'});
```

Now I am getting the below stateparams

```
console.log($stateParams.id) -> '7';(expected)
console.log($stateParams.date) -> '06/09/2016';(which shouldn't be right here.)
```

$stateParams.date should be undefined because I didn't pass it while calling the state. But In the Url by default It was passing, once I was passed it. As It was optional param so it should be neglected while not passing. How to make it 'Undefined' while calling the same state again without passing the param? I know If I passed $stateParams.date=null or someother name It will reflected. But I dont need to pass via my router url? Is there any other way to achieve this?

**UPDATE 1:**
After the posted answer I used '{inherit:false}' as the expected results. But It didn't inherit any of the param values which I wasn't passed while calling the state. But I don't want to inherit only optional param values. See the below code.

```
  $stateProvider.state('test', {
   url: '/page/:id/:type?date',
   controller: 'MyCtrl'       
 });
```

Here I am having to dynamic param id and type. If suppose I called with updated value of id only then type is not inherited. But I want to inherit type param value not the date (conditional Param) value.

```
$state.go("test", {id: '3'},{inherit:false});
```

console.log($stateParams.type) -> undefined.(here I want the 'type' param value should be inherited without passing. becaz I don't want update the value of 'type'. I just want the previous value should be maintain. Anyway to achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add another argument to the function call; `{inherit:false}` tells `$state.go()` not to inherit previous values.

```
$state.go("test", {id: '7'}, {inherit: false});
```

The default for `inherit` is `true`, as described in [the docs here](https://angular-ui.github.io/ui-router/site/#/api/ui.router.state.$state).

Comment: How can we inherit dynamic param 'id' here and not to inherit query param 'date'?

Comment: {inherit:false} should not be inherited any param values. But I don't want to inherit only optional param values.

Comment: is there any way to inherit only dynamic param values?@C14L

Comment: I am not sure what you mean. Could you edit your question and clarify what exactly you need? That way, others will see it too, and may be able to help.

Comment: hope now you understand my question. @C14L

Comment: any comments...@C14L